# Finding closed formula for sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

How can I find the closed formula for the sequence $$S = 2^0n + 2^{1}(n-1) + 2^{2}(n-2) + ... + 2^{n-1}(1) + 2^{n}(0).$$
Also, what kind of sequence is this because it looks both geometric and arithmetic.

Comment: Looks like it is $S_n=\sum_{i=0}^n 2^i(n-i)=n\sum_{i=0}^n2^i-\sum_{i=0}^ni2^i$ and you should be able to handle both of those sums.

Comment: See [arithmetico-geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetico%E2%80%93geometric_sequence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$S_{n}-S_{n-1} =2^0 + 2^1+\cdots + 2^{n-1}=2^n-1$$

$$S_n-S_1 = (S_n-S_{n-1}) + (S_{n-1}-S_{n-2}) + \cdots + (S_2-S_1) \\
= (2^n-1)+(2^{n-1}-1)+ \cdots + (2^2-1)=2^{n+1}-2^2 - (n-1)$$

$$\implies S_n = 2^{n+1} - n-2. \blacksquare $$